# gnupg broken after power outage

Tags: gpg

Recently I happend to experience a quite unpleasant power outage
which caused my system to go down unexpectadly. After power came
back the system came back as well and other than a fsck being required
all seemed fine. The unedifying surprise hit me when I first tried
to access my pass password store - it complained about gpg being broken;
so I checked with plain

```
gpg
```

and got this:

```
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/home/meUser/.gnupg/.#lk0x14368b8.meBox.13459': Not a directory
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/meUser/.gnupg/secring.gpg': general error
gpg: failed to create temporary file `/home/meUser/.gnupg/.#lk0x14379f0.meBox.13459': Not a directory
gpg: keyblock resource `/home/meUser/.gnupg/pubring.gpg': general error
```

Does this mean that gnupg is broken on my system now or is this something
user specific? I guess my password store is gone, just wondering how to fix gpg to set up a new store.

Comment: are you sure `fsck` completed successfully?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /home/meUser/.gnupg`?

Comment: @casey: fixed some inodes to lost+found, other than that: yes.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: srwx----wT 33542 2147486432 3626238453 1093671686 Mar 22  1951 /home/meUser/.gnupg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your folder `/home/meUser/.gnupg` is gone. You have to restore it from `lost+found` or backup.

Comment: of course I managed not to have a backup of that, also have looked into restoring from lost and found. as I have a hard copy of the passwords I'd rather just create a new store. how can I fix .gnupg? just delete dir .gnupg and run gpg?

Comment: @KB22 Not to have a backup of the keyrings seems crazy. What do you mean with "hard copy of the **passwords**"? If you delete `/home/meUser/.gnupg` and run `gpg` afterwards it should recreate the folder with an empty public and private keyring and trust database.

Comment: not much to bring up in my defense as far backup is concerned. Hard Copy: piece of paper, passwords written on it. gpg fixed as you described - thanks! one more thing: seem to be unable to delete .password-store - getting rm: cannot remove `.password-store/vpn/someThing.gpg': Operation not permitted even with sudo

Comment: `The reasons I know for nor being able to delete are (1) file system errors, (2) SELinux, AppArmor and the like, (3) file system attributes: `lsattr .password-store/vpn/someThing.gpg`.

Comment: lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on - tried to chmod it to 0755. Not permitted either.

Comment: chattr -i didn't work either, interesting.

Comment: @KB22 `lsattr` / `chattr` is specific for ext2/3/4.

Comment: nevermind, this is a different topic - not gpg related. thanks very much for helping me out. Will sagen: vielen Dank.